# How to use the new auto sizing feature of UITableViewCell in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a custom UITableViewCell subclass, and say there is a UIPickerView inside of it. As far as I know the cell requires constraints on both its top and its bottom so that the height can be calculated. The problem is when I specify only the top and bottom constraints, the height of the cell displayed is like 44. So I added a height constraint for the UIPickerView to be 162, then the console says all these constraints cannot be satisfied simultaneously.

So how can I let the estimated height to be 162 so that the UIPickerView is displayed properly (Without overriding the height function of UITableViewDelegate?)

Comment: Did you provide datasource for 'UIPickerView', if so it will expand the cell height, do not set height constraint for the picker.

Comment: hey @gabbler I just figured out the conflict is caused by 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7bf99180(43.5)] which I guess is telling the cell height should be 43.5. So is there anyway to remove this auto generated constraint?

Comment: I don't think it has something to do with that, if you don't set height constraint for the picker, you will not have conflict.

Comment: yeah but the height will be 44 as UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height constraint has specified.

Comment: No, it will not. I just verified that, I had set datasource for picker.

Comment: Yeah I don't have to specify the height for the picker. @gabbler thanks for that and I get it fixed by setting "tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension". But now it seems that cells are not properly sized for the first time so I have to call tableView.reloadData() after viewDidAppear(). Is that a bug?

Comment: Set estimatedRowHeight and see what happens.